# React js. Passing Props to the index.js file gives me an 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Here's my ToDoComp.js file

```
class ToDoComp extends Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1> {this.props.product.name} </h1>

            </div>
            );
    }
}

 var prod={"id":2,"name":"An ice sculpture","price":"12.50"};
 export default ToDoComp;
```

my index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(<ToDoComp  product={prod} />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I'm getting an error like this

./src/index.js
Line 8:  'prod' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Is 'prod' defined in index.js i can see it `TodoComp`.

Comment: No it is not.It's only in ToDoComp

Comment: why pass it as a prop if it is defined in `ToDoComp`?

Comment: Shouldn't I pass an array as a prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And indeed (as the error says) `prod` is not defined, since you did not exported it in ToDoComp.js.

You can do something like this at the end of your ToDoComp.js:
`export prod;` and then at the begginning of index.js you can import it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is defined outside the class, it should be declared before the render:

```
class ToDoComp extend Component {
  var prod={"id":2,"name":"An ice sculpture","price":"12.50"};

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1> {this.props.product.name} </h1>

        </div>
        );
  }
}
export default ToDoComp;
```